# Shipping Cost Extra

Tags: vb.net

Am having problem with shipping extra cost in vb 2010 , The question is to calculate the extra handling charge of $5.00 per part for an oversize container (the Oversize Container CheckBox is checked). Below is the code i have worked on for the shipping rate . I have define oversize as constant but i cant get it to work

What we are told to do is to make sure when the oversizedcheckbox is checked it should calculate the oversize amount which is $5 per unit and it should be added to any shipping charges that has been selected . In my case i have 4 shipping which is

ups $7 per unit , us postal air $8.5 per unit , fedex ground $9.2 per unit  and fedex air  $12 per unit

```
Public Class Lab5


'ship mode constants
Const U_P_S_DECIMAL As Decimal = 7D
Const FED_EX_AIR_DECIMAL As Decimal = 12D
Const FED_EX_GROUND_DECIMAL As Decimal = 9.25D
Const US_POSTRAL_AIR_DECIMAL As Decimal = 8.5D


Const SALES_TAX_RATE_SINGLE As Single = 0.1 '10 Percent Rate

'declear module-level variables
Private TotalQuantityInteger As Integer
Private TotalSalesDecimal As Decimal




Private Sub ComputeButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComputeButton.Click, ComputeToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Try


        Dim TotalCostDecimal, ShippingCostDecimal, SalesTaxDecimal, OversizeDecimal, TotalDueDecimal As Decimal


        'Declare variables and convert value from textbox controls to memory
        Dim PriceDecimal As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(PriceTextBox.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)
        Dim QuantityInteger As Integer = Integer.Parse(QuantityTextBox.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Number)

        'Process - Compute values
        'Subtotal = price times the quantity of books
        TotalCostDecimal = PriceDecimal * QuantityInteger



        'Sales tex = sales tax rate times the subtotal minus discount amount
        If RetailCheckBox.Checked Then
            SalesTaxDecimal = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(TotalCostDecimal * SALES_TAX_RATE_SINGLE), 2)
        End If


        If CustomerIDMaskedTextBox.MaskCompleted = False Then
            'incomplete telephone number
            MessageBox.Show("Incomplete or missing CustomerID", "CustomerID Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            CustomerIDMaskedTextBox.Focus()
            CustomerIDMaskedTextBox.SelectAll()
        ElseIf NameTextBox.Text.Trim = String.Empty Then
            'Customer name is required
            MessageBox.Show("Customer Name is required", "Customer Name Missing Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            NameTextBox.Focus()
            NameTextBox.SelectAll()
        ElseIf StateTextBox.Text.Trim = String.Empty Then
            'Shipping address required
            MessageBox.Show("State is required", "State Missing Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            StateTextBox.Focus()
            StateTextBox.SelectAll()
        ElseIf PartTextBox.Text.Trim = String.Empty Then
            'Missing Part Number Required
            MessageBox.Show("Part Number is missing", "Part Number Missing Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            PartTextBox.Focus()
            PartTextBox.SelectAll()
        ElseIf DescriptionTextBox.Text.Trim = String.Empty Then
            'Description is Required
            MessageBox.Show("Product Description is missing", "Product Description Missing Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            DescriptionTextBox.Focus()
            DescriptionTextBox.SelectAll()
        ElseIf IsNumeric(PriceTextBox.Text) = False Then
            'the purchase price textbox must contain a numeric value
            MessageBox.Show("Price must contain a numeric value", "Price Not Numeric Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            PriceTextBox.Focus()
            PriceTextBox.SelectAll()
        ElseIf IsNumeric(QuantityTextBox.Text) = False Then
            'the Quantity purchased Testbox must contain a numeric value
            MessageBox.Show("Quantity must be input", "Quantity Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            QuantityTextBox.Focus()
            QuantityTextBox.SelectAll()
        ElseIf Decimal.Parse(QuantityTextBox.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Number) < 0 Then
            'the quantity purchased must be greater than zero
            MessageBox.Show("The quantity must be greater than zero", "Quantity Purchased not greater than zero Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
        End If


        'Shipping cost

        If UPSRadioButton.Checked Then 'compute the shipping cost
            ShippingCostDecimal = U_P_S_DECIMAL * QuantityInteger

        ElseIf FedExAirRadioButton.Checked Then
            ShippingCostDecimal = FED_EX_AIR_DECIMAL * QuantityInteger

        ElseIf FedExGroundRadioButton.Checked Then
            ShippingCostDecimal = FED_EX_GROUND_DECIMAL * QuantityInteger

        ElseIf USPostalAirRadioButton.Checked Then
            ShippingCostDecimal = US_POSTRAL_AIR_DECIMAL * QuantityInteger

        End If

        'Compute TotalDue
        TotalDueDecimal = SalesTaxDecimal + ShippingCostDecimal + TotalCostDecimal

        'Data computed output
        SubtotalTextBox.Text = TotalCostDecimal.ToString("C")
        TotalDueTextBox.Text = TotalDueDecimal.ToString("C2")
        SalesTaxTextBox.Text = SalesTaxDecimal.ToString("N")
        ShippingCostTextBox.Text = ShippingCostDecimal.ToString("N")

        'Accumulate total sales and total books sold
        TotalQuantityInteger += QuantityInteger
        TotalSalesDecimal += TotalDueDecimal
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("unexpected error", "Compute Button Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add to your question a better explanation of what is not working now.

Comment: You say you need to add an oversize rate of $5 but this line OversizeDecimal = ShippingCostDecimal * OVERSIZE_RATE_DECIMAL seem to be multiplying by 5....

Comment: What we are told to do is to make sure when the oversizedcheckbox is checked it should calculate the oversize amount which is $5 per unit and it should be added to any shipping charges that has been selected . In my case i have 4 shipping which is

ups $7 per unit , us postal air $8.5 per unit , fedex ground $9.2 per unit and fedex air $12 per unit

Comment: So where in your code are you checking that the oversizecheckbox is checked? It seems to me that you have just posted your assignment add a line calculating Oversize_Rate_Decimal (incorrectly in my opinion) and then not even adding your calculation to the TotalDueDecimal... ???? You need to try harder.

Comment: @Ayodele OK... I appreciate that you may be new to vb but you need to give more accurate information to get reasonable help. I tried to help by second guessing. Others will not even bother doing that. So explain exactly what is not working. Currently you mention oversizecheckbox but you have no code checking if this is checked. You mention you have to ADD an Oversize rate whereas it seems you are MULTIPLYING. Give more details.

Comment: What we are told to do is to make sure when the oversizedcheckbox is checked it should calculate the oversize amount which is $5 per unit and it should be added to any shipping charges that has been selected . In my case i have 4 shipping which is ups $7 per unit , us postal air $8.5 per unit , fedex ground $9.2 per unit and fedex air $12 per unit .... I dont really know how to calculate it that is why am on here

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment....
You say you need to add an oversize rate of $5 but this line

```
OversizeDecimal = ShippingCostDecimal * OVERSIZE_RATE_DECIMAL
```

seem to be multiplying by 5
Try

```
 OversizeDecimal = ShippingCostDecimal + (OVERSIZE_RATE_DECIMAL * QuantityInteger)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out myself

Public Class Lab5

```
'ship mode constants
Const U_P_S_DECIMAL As Decimal = 7D
Const FED_EX_AIR_DECIMAL As Decimal = 12D
Const FED_EX_GROUND_DECIMAL As Decimal = 9.25D
Const US_POSTRAL_AIR_DECIMAL As Decimal = 8.5D
Const OVERSIZE_RATE_DECIMAL As Decimal = 5D

Const SALES_TAX_RATE_SINGLE As Single = 0.1 '10 Percent Rate

        'Oversized Handling Charges
        If OversizedCheckBox.Checked Then
            ShippingCostDecimal = QuantityInteger * (OVERSIZE_RATE_DECIMAL + U_P_S_DECIMAL)

        ElseIf OversizedCheckBox.Checked Then
            ShippingCostDecimal = QuantityInteger * (OVERSIZE_RATE_DECIMAL + FED_EX_AIR_DECIMAL)

        ElseIf OversizedCheckBox.Checked Then
            ShippingCostDecimal = QuantityInteger * (OVERSIZE_RATE_DECIMAL + FED_EX_GROUND_DECIMAL)

        ElseIf OversizedCheckBox.Checked Then
            ShippingCostDecimal = QuantityInteger * (OVERSIZE_RATE_DECIMAL + US_POSTRAL_AIR_DECIMAL)
        End If
```